# wicked_pdf in ruby on rails sidekiq worker: how to make the template used dynamic

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, pdf, sidekiq, wicked-pdf

I have a sidekiq worker with a private method inside it that uses wicked_pdf to change an HTML file into a pdf then upload it to AWS s3 and return the URL, here's my private method inside the sidekiq worker.

```
  def build_invoice_statistics_pdf()
    @number_of_users = 5
    pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
        ApplicationController.renderer.new.render(
        template: "store_portal/cities/show.html.erb",
        layout: "layouts/pdf.html.erb",
        formats: [:html])
     )
    s3_public_url = upload_pdf_to_s3(pdf)
    s3_public_url
  end
```

And I'm using that HTML file as a template, my problem is I want to pass a variable or a value to that HTML file, to make it a dynamic file, for example, I want to pass @number_of_users variable
to the HTML file. here are my HTML template code and my layout code

show.html.erb

```
<%= @number_of_users %>
```

pdf.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <style>
        td, th {
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            padding: 8px;
        }
        th {
            padding-top: 12px;
            padding-bottom: 12px;
            text-align: left;
            background-color: #7e827e;
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
<body>
    <%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

the variable `@number_of_users` value is always `nil`, any solutions please on how to pass it to the html file which is used as template for `wicked_pdf`?

Answer (score 0):

Wicked is looking for `@number_of_users` in the `store_portal/cities_controller.rb` controller's show action. Put it there.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add locals the render method, in order to pass variables to the template. More details [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Renderer.html). Make sure to change @number_of_users in your template to number_of_users (without the @).

```
pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
    ApplicationController.renderer.new.render(
    template: "store_portal/cities/show.html.erb",
    layout: "layouts/pdf.html.erb",
    locals:{ number_of_users: @number_of_users }
    formats: [:html])
 )
```